# How to connect to Postgres Server using Flutter?

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I've recently installed PostgreSql and want to connect it with my flutter app.
I've used [postgres 2.4.3](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres) plugin to connect with the DB.
But when I use this code to access the DB:

```
var connection = PostgreSQLConnection("localhost", 5432, "new-app",
      username: "postgres", password: "12345");
await connection.open();
```

it gives me connection refused error, what should I do to connect my PostgresSQL DB to flutter?